# convert a text file output to a html format using bash

Tags: bash, awk

HI am trying to convert a text file to html with table so that i could mail the output in a table format and i used `awk 'BEGIN{print "Content-Type: text/html; charset="us-ascii""\n "<html>"\n "<Body>"\n "<table>"} {print "<tr>";for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)print "<td>" $i"</td>";print "</tr>"} END{print \n</Body>"\n "</html>"\n"</table>"}' a.txt >> email.html` but am having problems could some one help me on this

Answer (score 2):

You need to clean your line. The `\n` need to be in double quote like this:

```
awk '
BEGIN{
    print "Content-Type: text/html; charset=us-ascii\n <html>\n <Body>\n<table>"
    } 
    {print "<tr>"
    for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)
        print "<td>" $i"</td>"
    print "</tr>"
    }
END{
    print "\n</Body>\n</html>\n</table>"
    }' a.txt >> email.html
```

Comment: Cool .. but `cat email.html | sendmail -t tmp@exmple.com` doesn't work am not able to recieve the output with tables

Answer (score 2):

**-Edited-**  It works with this:

```
awk '
BEGIN{
    print "Content-Type: text/html; charset="us-ascii"\n<html>\n<head>\n<style>\ntable                 ,   th,td\n{\n border:1px solid black;
    border-collapse:collapse;\n}\n</style>\n</head>\n<Body>\n<table>"
    } 
    {print "<tr>"
    for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)
        print "<td>" $i"</td>"
    print "</tr>"
    }
    END{
    print "\n</table>\n</Body>\n</html>\n" 
    }' a.txt >> email.html
```